# turnoff/disable case sensitive in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

How can i turnoff/diable case sensitive in AutoMapper in IDataReader? Ex:

```
using (IDataReader dr = DatabaseContext.ExecuteReader(command))
        {
            if (dr.FieldCount > 0)
            {
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, IList<AnyDataModel>>();
                var data = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<AnyDataModel>>(dr);
                return data;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Any help?